# How to uninstall Bluecherry security cam software

Tags: 21.04

I was testing a video cam for a client and installed Bluecherry Beta on my Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 machine. Never worked well enough to use so I've ignored it for a month and it didn't seem to bother anything.

But yesterday, installed 21.04 LTS and it complained, giving the White Screen of Death, and gave notice that it couldn't deal with Bluecherry. So after 21.04 was up and running, I tried to uninstall. And it won't. At least not completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bluecherry
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/bluecherry
```

I found that didn't work as I could still run the program so I did a search and deleted all the files for it I could find in the only directory I found that had any Bluecherry files.

That still didn't work. The program was still there and still ran fine, and the 'Bluecherry DVR' entry was still in the drop down I use to reboot. Dunno what that dropdown is called. 'Exit' or 'Shutdown' menu or something?

Went into Synaptic manager and deleted it there. The program was no longer there and no longer shows up in a program search, but "Bluecherry DVR" is still in the dropdown. I'm using Mate.

How can I edit that menu to delete Bluecherry DVR? It doesn't launch anything when I click it so this is the last of it.

**Edit**

Installed it more than a month ago, and haven't used it much since then except to evaluate it, but I believe this is what I used to install:

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install solo6010-dkms bluecherry
```

Here is the link I used to their website: [Bluecherry Surveillance Software](https://www.bluecherrydvr.com/features-3/)

**Edit:** I attempted to get rid of the Bluecherry DVR listing in the Mate dropdown menu without success UNTIL I upgraded to Ubuntu V22.04 and that did the trick. It's gone from the dropdown menu attached to the upper panel. Case closed.

Comment: Depends on how you installed it. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1356459/edit) to add the information about how you installed this software.

Comment: What was the exact command you used to install it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ran it with a wildcard '*'

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bluecherry*
```

the package it found and removed was 'bluecherry-client' and that got rid of it.

Comment: Well, that did seem to help as Bluecherry DVR doesn't run now, but I still have that Bluecherry DVR link in the drop down menu. So I need to find out how to edit that menu I guess. There was an error message that, "/var/lib/dpkg/info/bluecherry.postrm: line 37: mysql: command not found
dpkg: error processing package bluecherry (--purge):
 installed bluecherry package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127" Which means some part of the routine can't be found. But still, Bluecherry is still on my menu. Thanks for the help.